# Office 365 CRM and Sharepoint Online How to Get SAML Token for Current Logged in User

Tags: dynamics-crm, office365, dynamics-crm-online, sharepoint-online

So I have CRM Online and SharePoint Online as document storage.  I have the list component installed and everything is working there.  I have a plugin I have built which generates emails, and as part of the process, grabs documents from various SharePoint folders and attaches the to the email before sending.

To do this in a SharePoint online environment, I have to go out, grab a SAML token from MS's login STS service, pass the token to SharePoint, receive a couple of authentication cookies back, and pass those cookies along with any requests I make to SharePoint.  All of this is working.  The bad news is I have to have a username and password hardcoded in (or prompt the user).  Is there any way from inside CRM Online to grab the current user's credentials and pass that to get the SAML token?  I mean there has to be since CRM does it when you create the document libraries when you turn on Document Management, right?

I can't use the SharePoint dlls inside CRM Online plugins, it is security restricted.  I cannot access the CredentialCache, security restricted.  Hell, I even looked at trying to intercept the cookies somehow with Javascript, but it looks like they are HTTPOnly and pretty much inaccessible.

Tried putting in a Microsoft ticket and got some low level guy who immediately passed the buck and called it unsupported.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that CRM creates the folders for Document Management on the back-end? I always thought - based on the user experience - that this was being done though client-side JavaScript. Everything I've ever seen would indicate this a client-side activity but I've never looked under the covers to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get user's password in CRM. If you are developing a plugin, the plugin can run in the user context and the code will execute based on the logged in user. Therefore you don't need to pass any creds for adding a document in CRM.

Check out this url, it helps you understanding how impersonating works in CRM.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309416.aspx

Hope this helps.